# jquery function not apply to get append page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <script>
    function textoverflow(ele, num){
        ele.each(function(){
            var count = $(this).text().length;
            if(count > num){
                var org = $(this).text();
                $(this).text($(this).text().slice(0,num) + '... ').append('<span class="readMore">More</span>');
            }

            $('.readMore').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().text(org);
            });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        textoverflow($('.text'),10);

        $(document).delegate('#click', 'click', function(){

            $.get('/newpage.php', function(data){
                $('div').append(data);
            }); 
        });

    });
    </script>
    <p class="text">abcdefghijklmnopq</p>
    <p class="text">abcdefghijklmnopq</p>

    <a id="click">Click me</a><br />
    <div></div>

//newpage.php
<p class="text">abcdefghijklmnopq</p>
<p class="text">abcdefghijklmnopq</p>
```

I have a function can truncate multiple line text and append a button More,

it works fine but when i try to use jquery get append data from another page, this function does not apply to new page.

http://jsfiddle.net/CsHwN/

is any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `textoverflow` function after result from ajax is appended to div. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CsHwN/3/)

Comment: i did before, but it glitch, previous text will slice back and button wont work

Comment: I've added jsfiddle demo to answer.

Comment: do i must change class name? i notice my problem is cause by same class name

Comment: no you don't if you won't have more <div> elements.

Comment: weird, i try same class name and it glitch

Comment: this work, not good.... your answer means to attach a event handler to all `.readMore` elements everytime you click the button. the proformance is terrible

Answer (score 0):

first

```
$('.readMore').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().text(org);
            })
```

don't put this code inside each, put it out side each, and use `on` instend of click, because the data is dynamicly attached to the div,

```
    $('body').on('click','.readMore',function(){
                    $(this).parent().text(org);
                })
```

then

```
function textoverflow(ele, num){
    ele.each(function(){
        var count = $(this).text().length;
        if(count > num){
            var org = $(this).text();
            $(this).data('origin-text',org);
            $(this).text($(this).text().slice(0,num) + '... ').append('<span class="readMore">More</span>');
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    textoverflow($('.text'),10);

    $(document).delegate('#click', 'click', function(){
        $('div').append('<p class="text">abcdefghijklmnopq</p>');
       textoverflow($('div .text'),10);
    });

    $('body').on('click','.readMore',function(){
        $(this).parent().text($(this).parent().data('origin-text'));
    });
});
```

then save the org text in the `data`, so, textoverflow only take care of truncet text.